# CSS styling for every second div in a list

Tags: css

I have `div` boxes on my website. Every second box should have a border in another color.

In one case the `div`s appear as a list. I cannot change the HTML code because it is automatically generated. On the other parts of my website I do the styling like this and it works:

```
.displayBlogpost:nth-child(2n+1) {
    border: #B4C556 1px solid;
}
```

But with the `ol` that does not work anymore. I have no idea how to get access to every second `.displayBlogpost-div`. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8SbbL/

Comment: is the list dynamically generated (and something you can control) or do you create it in static HTML

Answer (score 17, accepted):

to make use of the nth-child you need to apply it to the list item,

http://jsfiddle.net/8SbbL/6/

you can also use `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` which reads nicer than your `2n-1`

Comment: This `nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd)` is simple and works well. It makes the coding clean even more. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The element is within an li, so it is always the first and last element.  Use the n-th child trick on the actual li.

```
#searchresult li:nth-child(2n+1) .displayBlogpost {
    border: #B4C556 1px solid;
}
```

Working fork: http://jsfiddle.net/FJuzm/